# Creating a graph from a table with time differences

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, windows-10, microsoft-excel-2016

How do I create a graph like this

[image]

from a table that looks like this

```
startTime;endTime;Name
00:00:04;23:59:57;Peter
00:00:00;23:59:59;Frank
...
```

?

Answer (score 0):

After you added the additional information, I was able to make the chart you want as follows:

[image]

Select the entire data table, including the headings at the top and left.  Then choose "Stacked Bar" from the Bar chart tab.

If the graph is created with 3 bars (mine was) click on the chart to select it and click "Switch Row/Column" in the "Source Data..." dialog under the Chart menu.

The blank space to the left of the red bar is a section of the stacked bar that has to be formatted with "No Fill" and "No Shadow". Double-click on that section to open the "Format Data Series" dialog.

If your data table has only one row of EndTimes, the bars will be the same color, but that may be OK for you.

Comment: Justified question. I updated my post.

Comment: All the bar charts in Excel have bars that start at the origin.  So you can't do what you're asking using an Excel bar chart.  You might try to fiddle with a scatter graph, assigning y-values for the "elevations" of the bars and format the lines of the data series to be very thick, but that would be a real kluge and not a productive use of time.  If you really need to have the graph look like your illustration, find a graphics program that will do "box and whisker" charts.  Good luck.

Comment: On second thought, you *CAN* do this in Excel.  You'll need to make a *stacked" bar chart with two stacked bars.  Then format the portion of the bar closest to the origin to be invisible.  Let me know if you have trouble with that and I'll post an example tomorrow.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with gantt-diagrams?

Comment: Microsoft shows how to create Gantt charts on [this help page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Present-your-data-in-a-Gantt-chart-f8910ab4-ceda-4521-8207-f0fb34d9e2b6).  The technique is just what I described above - formatting portions of the bars with "no fill".  It works OK, but it's hard to get the visible bars to be different colors.  You can add a dummy bar to one series and un-fill that one also.  Suggest you try the examples on that website and see how it works for you.